# Python - Divide the column into multiple columns using Split

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe like this {each row in B is a string with values joined with | symbol}:

```
A B
a 1|2|3
b 2|4|5
c 3|2|5
```

I want to create columns which say that the value is present in that row(of column B) or not:

```
A B     1 2 3 4 5
a 1|2|3 1 1 1 0 0
b 2|4|5 0 1 0 1 1
c 3|5   0 0 1 0 1
```

I have tried this by looping the columns. But, can it be done using lambda or comprehensions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
print df
   A      B
0  a  1|2|3
1  b  2|4|5
2  c  3|2|5

print df.B.str.get_dummies(sep='|')
   1  2  3  4  5
0  1  1  1  0  0
1  0  1  0  1  1
2  0  1  1  0  1
```

And if you need old column `B` use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
print df.join(df.B.str.get_dummies(sep='|'))
   A      B  1  2  3  4  5
0  a  1|2|3  1  1  1  0  0
1  b  2|4|5  0  1  0  1  1
2  c  3|2|5  0  1  1  0  1
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Also we can use `pandas.concat([df,df.B.str.get_dummies(sep='|')],axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

```
In [19]: df
Out[19]: 
   A      B
0  a  1|2|3
1  b  2|4|5
2  c  3|2|5

In [20]: op = df.merge(df.B.apply(lambda s: pd.Series(dict((col, 1)  for col in s.split('|')))), 
left_index=True, right_index=True).fillna(0)

In [21]: op
Out[21]: 
   A      B  1  2  3  4  5
0  a  1|2|3  1  1  1  0  0
1  b  2|4|5  0  1  0  1  1
2  c  3|2|5  0  1  1  0  1
```